# IOS swift, random crash with String and UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm having weird problem with my app

**Environment: Xcode 7.1.1**

I'm writing in swift and having random crashes, I have the next functions:

```
private func _generateTitleButton(frame: CGRect,title:String)->UIButton{
    //Font Property:
    let buttonFont = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 13)!;

    let button = UIButton(frame:frame);
    //crash point
    button.setTitle(title, forState: .Normal); 
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal);
    button.titleLabel!.font = buttonFont;
    button.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Top;
    button.addTarget(self, action: "titleButtonClicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown);
    return button;
}
```

I summon the function when the actual string is an enum raw value:

```
private enum titleButtonsText : String{
    case NOTES  = "NOTES";
    case PEOPLE = "PEOPLE";
    case INFO   = "INFO";
}
```

function use:

```
self.infoButton = self._generateTitleButton(CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: baseX, y: originY), size: buttonSize),title:titleButtonsText.INFO.rawValue);
```

in the `_generateTitleButton` the `title:String` is for some reason the next string:

**retain\0release\0autorelease\0retainCount\0zone\0hash\0superclass\0description\0debugDescription\0scrollViewDidScroll:\0scrollViewDidZoom:\0scrollViewWillBeginDragging:\0scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:\0scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:\0scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:\0scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:\0scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:\0viewForZoomingInScrollView:\0scrollViewWillBeginZooming:withView:\0scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:\0scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:\0scrollViewDidScrollToTop:\0_performScrollTest:withIterations:rowsToScroll:inComponent:\0tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:\0tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:\0numberOfSectionsInTableView:\0tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:\0tableView:titleForFooterInSection:\0tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:\0tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:\0sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:\0tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:\0tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:\0tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:\0setSoundsEnabled:\0reload\0reloadDataForColumn**

print of `self` in crash point:

```
self = 0x0000000000000010 {
  UIKit.UIView = {
    UIKit.UIResponder = {
      ObjectiveC.NSObject = {}
    }
  }
  backButton = <read memory from 0x178 failed (0 of 8 bytes read)>

  infoButton = <read memory from 0x180 failed (0 of 8 bytes read)>

  peopleButton = <read memory from 0x188 failed (0 of 8 bytes read)>

  notesButton = <read memory from 0x190 failed (0 of 8 bytes read)>

  _border = <read memory from 0x198 failed (0 of 8 bytes read)>

  title = <read memory from 0x1a0 failed (0 of 8 bytes read)>

  saveButton = <read memory from 0x1a8 failed (0 of 8 bytes read)>

  deleteButton = <read memory from 0x1b0 failed (0 of 8 bytes read)>

  titleLabel = <read memory from 0x1b8 failed (0 of 8 bytes read)>

}
```

p.s the class is singleton `static var instance = CalendarMeetingViewTitle()`

The only change I did recently is adding push notification support with parse to the app and changing the button target to another method, it worked so far for the last few months

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, for some reason it is with the singleton.
changing

```
static var instance = CalendarMeetingViewTitle()
```

to

```
private static var _instance : CalendarMeetingViewTitle?
static var instance :CalendarMeetingViewTitle{
    if _instance == nil{
        _instance = CalendarMeetingViewTitle();
    }
    return _instance!;
}
```

solves the problem